# This build is configured to query EAS Update for updates, however no channel is set in eas.json

Tags: react-native, expo

When I build my EAS project I'm getting the following warning.

```
This build is configured to query EAS Update for updates, however no channel is set in eas.json.
```

My eas.json looks like this:

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.8.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "staging": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "channel": "staging"
    },
  }
}
```

What do I need to do for the warning to go away / be able to send updates to my app?

Answer (score 0):

reading the documentation, you need to configure a channel for the updates in the eas.json file.

Try adding the following code:

```
"production": {
      "channel": "production"
    },
    "preview": {
      "channel": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal"
```

based on https://docs.expo.dev/build/updates/

Comment: How is that different from what I have, beyond you are using different environment names?

Comment: try the following

"cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.8.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "staging" change here to "production" : {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "channel": "staging"
    },
  }
}


this should solve your problem.